# Pop-Up JS Gallery Images Getting Duplicated

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, categories, prettyphoto

http://2012.delineamultimedia.com/delinea_new_12.html#home_portfolio_botm_bg

This portfolio template has a section that includes what looks to be a wordpress plugin for an HTML template(this is all html, css, and js that i'm using, no wordpress)... the plugin looks to be duplicating fancybox and prettyPhoto popup images that are associated with the "rel" attribute. If you click on the "image no 1" icon you will see that prettyPhoto is associated with this popup and its showing 2 images in the gallery when in the markup I've only linked to 1 image.

I found out that the line on this script...http://2012.delineamultimedia.com/js/script.js
that is one of the first lines down on the page.

```
$('.image-grid_' + (i+1) ).fGallery('.filter_' + (i+1) );
```

this loop seams to be causing the issue. Is there a way to alter this loop to NOT duplicate the pop-up images?

Comment: fancybox in not installed on your sample page

Comment: Okay I've commented out prettyPhoto and put fancybox back in. You can see that it starts on image 4/6 and that there are only 3 images in the markup that associated with the fancybox rel="group3"

Comment: your nivo slider seems to be cloning your tags this is why they are duplicated

Comment: some images are under `<ul id="image-grid"...` and others under `<ul id="grid_clone" ...`

Comment: If I comment out the nivo slider (both css and js) the problem still occurs though.

Comment: yea, I'm only seeing the #image-grid for some reason in my markup.

I still think it has something to do with this line... $('.image-grid_' + (i+1) ).fGallery('.filter_' + (i+1) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script [2012.delineamultimedia.com/js/fGallery.js](http://2012.delineamultimedia.com/js/fGallery.js) is cloning your images so this is why they are duplicated in either fancybox or prettyphoto:

```
var clone = element.clone().appendTo(element.parent()).attr('id','grid_clone');
```

Original images are under `<ul id="image-grid"...` and cloned images under `<ul id="grid_clone" ...`

Comment: Okay great, that helps! Thank you! Is there a way to alter that var to fix this?

Comment: well, that question sounds like you bought a house with structural problems, which it means you need to either get rid of that gallery script or get/build a new one.